# Where are the packages installed with `apt-get install` in Docker containers?

Tags: docker, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to locate the `libgsl.so` library in a Docker container after installing it successfully .

When I run an interactive shell with `docker run -it container/image bash` and try to find it `find / -iname "*libgsl*"` I get nothing (the tool tries to find it under /usr/lib/). It seems that the same is true for another successfully installed libraries (e.g. libjpeg62).

So, generally, **where are these libraries being installed**?

I'm running Docker with VBox in MacOS. 
Here is the `Dockerfile` file:

```
FROM phusion/baseimage

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  libgsl0ldbl \
  curl \
  gsl-bin

# Installs preseq from sources into /opt/
ENV PRESEQ_RELEASE=2.0
ENV PRESEQ_URL=http://smithlabresearch.org/downloads/preseq_linux_v${PRESEQ_RELEASE}.tar.bz2
ENV DEST_DIR=/opt/

# Download preseq; untar & decompress; remove tr.bz2 file; compile & install preseq; remove unnecessary files
RUN curl -SLo ${DEST_DIR}/preseq_v${PRESEQ_RELEASE}.tar.bz2 ${PRESEQ_URL} && \
  tar -xf ${DEST_DIR}/preseq_v${PRESEQ_RELEASE}.tar.bz2 -C ${DEST_DIR} && \
  rm -f ${DEST_DIR}/preseq_v${PRESEQ_RELEASE}.tar.bz2

ENV PATH=${DEST_DIR}/preseq_v${PRESEQ_RELEASE}:$PATH
CMD ["preseq"]
```

---

**UPDATE**

I was running the wrong container (not using the right tag) where I didn't have the library installed. After changing the tag, I found the libraries without a problem. Packages are installed in the default locations (in this case /usr/lib/).

Comment: Same place it normally gets installed. Where this is is package dependant.

Comment: That should be `/usr/lib/libgsl.so.0`, but is not there

Comment: Then what is your `docker build` and `docker run` commands exactly? I suspect you may be running the wrong thing.

Comment: Start a phusion/baseimage container, manually do an apt-get install, then do a `docker diff` on the running container to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks @Sobrique, it was just the wrong container being run

Answer (score 4):

Since `phusion/baseimage` use Ubuntu

Ask the package management what files the package contains:

```
dpkg -L libgsl0ldbl
```

This shows the files simply copied to those locations. These files are marked as managed by the package management